# How to develop an app for Cydia and jailbroken iPhones

Tags: iphone, xcode, jailbreak, cydia

I am starting to develop apps for iPhone. 
There is 1 specific app that I'd like to develop, but Apple will for sure reject it, so I want to do it for Cydia, cause I think it is just useful.

I'm trying to figure out how to use Theos and XCode to create my app, but I can't understand anything. I would be very glad if some of you could help me with this.

I have already installed Theos, and the header-dump scripts from Conor Burgess, but I just don't know how to start doint anything. How should I use XCode and Interface Builder with Theos to create my app? I have a mac, so I don't need any toolchain to develop on Windows. I also have my iPhone jailbroken, and I have been able to try on the iPhone some apps I had developed on XCode.

Which steps should I follow? I mean, if some of you is used to develop apps for cydia, what do you do? You create a new template with Theos, and then open your .mm file in XCode and create the .xib file?? Then when you are done, you compile it with XCode? Should I use ldid? Is there any guide for n00bs developers?

I have seen the templates Theos creates, and I think I need the Application one, cause I need some user interface, but maybe I'll need tweak too... There is not much info about it, I am just lost...

Thank you all very much in advance! 
Best regards!

Comment: Do you have any programming experience?

Comment: Yep! I do, PHP, Java, Javascript, C++,...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Theos application template will help you create a jailbreak application, but you won't be able to use Interface Builder for it without some extensive introspection. There is a module for Theos that allows you to compile xibs to nibs, but Interface Builder is awful and should not really be used for anything anyway.

In addition, Theos is what will handle compilation, and even signing using `ldid`. You simply run `make` to build your project, and then `make package` to package it in a .deb. You can install it to your device with `make install`.

Creating interfaces in code is not as difficult as it might seem.

If you need further assistance, check out the IRC channel #theos at irc.saurik.com. I hang out there, and, in fact, I'm the author of Theos.

Comment: Hi Dustin! First of all: Thank you veeery much for your answer! It's a privilege being answered by the author of Theos himself :) Thanks!

I'm still very lost in the world of jailbreak applications, and I would even feel just too noob to enter the irc channel to ask. I think I must keep on watching examples and examples and examples, and then enter the channel to ask specific questions, so that you don't fed up with me too early :D

You did a great job, thank you very very much again!

Regards, 
Joaquin.

Comment: Can I use Xcode to make these apps? I'm reading about Theos. I want to use it to make my Cydia tweaks (particularly interested in Notification Center widgets). I know you said we can't use IB (which I don't mind), can we use Xcode at all to make build the Theos projects and so on?