# Deploying MonoTouch-App on jailbroken iPad

Tags: ipad, xamarin.ios, jailbreak

I am learning to create Apps for the iPad via monoTouch by now.

For testingreasons I wanted to try out my app on the physical device (I know I need a pro/enterprise-licence from xamarin, and I will buy one). As we are not sure by now, what apple-dev.-program we want to subscrbe (pro, enterprise etc.), I wanted to try the stuff out by now on my iPad2 with jailbreak.

Is it possible to build for and debug on an iPad2 with monoTouch, *without* certificates and provisining files? And if how? All manuals I found  are for XCode or are the "normal" way to build your apps when you are already enrolled at apples dev-program.

Thanks in advance!

*UPDATE:* I am not talking about using MonoTouch without a license. I am talking about using a paid and activated version of MonoTouch without an Apple-Developer-Subscription. Sorry for the obfuscation.

Is there no possibilty to install your bought MonoTouch and start debugging on your device without being enrolled at an paid apple-subscription?

Comment: I'd venture not. The signing is part of what mdtool does. Anyways, you can always get the pro version and then upgrade to enterprise if you need ad-hoc deployment.

Comment: Just buy a license. The Xamarin guys do good work.

Comment: @Melissa: The Xamarin guys will get my money. I would not use their work without paying for it. (Please see my Update)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, developing for Cydia is pretty poorly documented--and will definitely have no documentation for MonoTouch.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788207/how-to-develop-an-app-for-cydia-and-jailbroken-iphones) discusses how to do it from XCode.  Also, checkout [saurik's site](http://www.saurik.com/), he discusses alot about Cydia on there.

You are in untested waters, but you might want to try signing with `ldid` and use the `--nosign` option in MonoTouch.

Comment: Shouldn't it be easier with the enterprise-deploying from monotouch? As soon as I have an *.ipa it should be easy to get it on the iPad?

Comment: @chiffre I think you still need a developer license even if you're going enterprise deployment

Comment: @after some time I/we decided to go the "official" way. There's also absolutely no support from Xamarin. So it's no fun at all.. ...the enterprise-release-way of apple is - well - anything but okay... but that's another topic.

Comment: @chiffre I know Xamarin explicitly doesn't support jailbroken devices, but just curious, is there a way to actually get it to work?

Comment: I got it to work a long time ago.  I could deploy over SFTP (ssh), but had to run some command line from the device afterward.  My problem was the fact that NSUserDefaults didn't work in the settings app as expected from a Cydia app, so I abandoned it (my app was using them alot).