# Create .ipa app on Xcode 4.5.2

Tags: xcode4.5

How can I create a .ipa file in the new Xcode and deploy it to my jailbroken iPhone 4S on iOS 5.1.1?

The .app in Xcode is red so I can't show it on Finder.

I'm not currently registered to the Apple developer program.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to *Archive* the project and then select *Export as Xcode Archive* (see this [Apple guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-archives_organizer/articles/distributing_ios_apps.html)).

You then need to find the Archive in Finder, which you can do by right-clicking the archive in Xcode and selecting *Show in Finder*.

To get it onto your phone you can use [Installous](http://hackulo.us/wiki/Installous).

Comment: The problem is that the Archive option under Product is grey so I can't.

Comment: @oridahan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266350/xcode-4-archive-is-greyed-out

Comment: OK this fixed the grey problem but now the Build fails, I get an error: "Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains".

Comment: @oridahan Hmmm, looks like what you wanted to ask was *How do I develop apps for a Jailbroken iPhone?* and not the one you actually asked; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788207/how-to-develop-an-app-for-cydia-and-jailbroken-iphones

Comment: Actually I just want to test the apps I'm currently writing without a registered developer account.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the built in archive command without a profile/certificate unless you [hack the SDK](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Xcode#Developing_without_Provisioning_Profile).

I haven't tested the above since iOS 6 and Xcode 4.2. I cant imagine a lot changed between 4.2 and 4.5. After applying those changes you can build with a self signed certificate or none at all.

I don't remember if this will allow you to directly use the IPA build in xcode, but if not it is trivial to make a build phase run a shell script to do so. here is one I made for [GemRB](https://github.com/gemrb/gemrb):

```
#increment the version number for the build
REV=`git log --pretty=format:'' | wc -l | sed 's/\ //g'`
VERSION=`git describe --tags --dirty=-patched`
DATE=`date -u +%Y-%m-%d\T%T\Z`

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $REV" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString $VERSION" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}"

#updtate the iTumesMetaData
cp ios/iTunesMetadata.plist.in ios/iTunesMetadata.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :softwareVersionExternalIdentifier $REV" "ios/iTunesMetadata.plist"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :releaseDate $DATE" "ios/iTunesMetadata.plist"

#make iOS ipa
#purge payload of everything
if [ -d `ios/Payload`];
then
rm -r ios/Payload;
fi
mkdir -p ios/Payload

WORKING_DIR=`pwd`

cp -r "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR"-iphoneos/GemRB.app ios/Payload/GemRB.app
cd ios
zip -r GemRB-ios-$VERSION.ipa iTunesArtWork iTunesMetadata.plist Payload

# copy the optional plugins
cd ..
cp "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR"/OGGReader.so "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$PLUGINS_FOLDER_PATH"/OGGReader.so
cp "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR"/PNGImporter.so "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$PLUGINS_FOLDER_PATH"/PNGImporter.so
```

obviously change some of the path variables and strip out the auto-version stuff if you don't want it.